# ndim in numpy array loaded with scipy.io.loadmat?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, mat-file

Using SciPy and MATLAB, I'm having trouble reconstructing an array to match what is given from a MATLAB cell array loaded using scipy.io.loadmat().

For example, say I create a cell containing a pair of double arrays in MATLAB and then load it using scipy.io (I'm using SPM to do imaging analyses in conjunction with pynifti and the like)

MATLAB

```
>> onsets{1} = [0 30 60 90]
>> onsets{2} = [15 45 75 105]
```

Python

```
>>> import scipy.io as scio
>>> mat = scio.loadmat('onsets.mat')
>>> mat['onsets'][0]
array([[[ 0 30 60 90]], [[ 15  45  75 105]]], dtype=object)

>>> mat['onsets'][0].shape

(2,)
```

My question is this: **Why does this numpy array have the shape (2,) instead of (2,1,4)**? In real life I'm trying to use Python to parse a logfile and build these onsets cell arrays, so I'd like to be able to build them from scratch.

When I try to build the same array from the printed output, I get a different shape back:

```
>>> new_onsets = array([[[ 0, 30, 60, 90]], [[ 15,  45,  75, 105]]], dtype=object)
array([[[0, 30, 60, 90]],

       [[15, 45, 75, 105]]], dtype=object)

>>> new_onsets.shape
(2,1,4)
```

Unfortunately, the shape (vectors of doubles in a cell array) is coded in a spec upstream, so I need to be able to get this saved exactly in this format. Of course, it's not a big deal since I could just write the parser in MATLAB, but it would be nice to figure out what's going on and add a little to my [minuscule] knowledge of numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis from the scipy mailing list responded that the right way to build this is to create the structure first, then populate the arrays:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/31760

```
> You could build what you saw before with: 
> 
> new_onsets = empty((2,), dtype=object) 
> new_onsets[0] = array([[0, 30, 60, 90]]) 
> new_onsets[1] = array([[15, 45, 75, 105]])
```

Comment: Came back to this again; scipy.io now has a very helpful reference for this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things I personally find kind of annoying in python. It is because `loadmat` automatically "squeezes" dimensions.

By default, squeeze_me=True so as you've seen you get this:

```
>>> x = sio.loadmat('mymat.mat',squeeze_me=True)
>>> y = x['onsets']
>>> y.shape
(2,)
```

If you use loadmat with squeeze_me set to False then you don't get one dimension squeezed out:

```
>>> a = sio.loadmat('mymat.mat',squeeze_me=False)
>>> a
>>> b = a['onsets']
>>> b.shape
(1, 2)
```

That said, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get another dimension to show up (that is, `b.shape = (1,2,4)`) for a cell array like 'onsets'. I've only been able to get it for non-cell plain-old vanilla MATLAB arrays

```
onset_array = [onsets{1}; onsets{2}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm not sure what squeeze_me is doing, but I'm still getting (2,) even with squeeze_me=False. (Maybe it's not looking far enough into the cell array?) I'll try to keep digging and let you know if I find anything. (Similarly, I'm not sure what do_compression is doing in savemat, but it didn't have an effect in any of my tests.

Comment: To build the dimensions correctly, the scipy list says to build the structure first with empty() and then populate it with data.

Comment: `annoying in python` No. Should be "annoying in **scipy**". Two *very* different things. scipy, numpy, matplotlib (note: all *3rd party external modules*) form a quite distinct world. In my experience some parts of them simply disregard pythonic philosophy in favor of their own. Not unambigously for the better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that cell arrays aren't really arrays, which is why `scio.loadmat` loads `onsets.mat` to an `object` array.

Here, your cell array could be reduced to a normal array of shape `(2,1,4)`, but what if, instead, your data looked like:

```
>> onsets{1} = {0 30 60 'bob'}
>> onsets{2} = {15 45 75 'fred'}
```

I'm not sure what the best solution is, but if you know your data is an array, you should probably convert to a normal array before saving in Matlab, or after loading with Scipy.

**Edit:** The example cell array above could, in theory, be cast into a numpy [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), but note that's not generally true of cell arrays because the columns don't have to be the same data type. The logical way to represent lists of arbitrary data types is with a Python list (or an array of lists, here), which is what `loadmat` returns.

**Edit 2:** Fix cell array syntax, as suggested by Erik Kastman.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a very numpy-compatible format, but it's what I need to use for another software package, so I'm locked into it. 

I think you need to be making cell arrays in the example above, like: {0 30 60 'bob'}; which would be nested cell arrays. I will always have arrays of doubles, so I don't need to worry about sub-cells or structs.